# Is my code slowing down because of how I am pulling my images from the database?

Tags: c#

I have code I have written that grabs images and orders them for further processing later on. I do this by instantiating a list and filling with the images seen below

```
var files = new List<GridFSFileInfo>();

if (progressAction != null)
    await progressAction("Preparing blocks...");

List<FlyerBlockImage> flyerBlockImages;

Stream imgStream;
Image img;

foreach (var b in blocks)
{
    if (b.Products == null)
        b.Products = new List<FlyerProduct>();

    var imagesForBlock = (await _blockRepo.FindDataForBlockAsync(b)).ToList();
    files.AddRange(imagesForBlock);

    flyerBlockImages = new List<FlyerBlockImage>();

    foreach (var item in imagesForBlock)
    {
        imgStream = await _blockRepo.OpenDataAsync(item.Id);
        img = Image.FromStream(imgStream);
        flyerBlockImages.Add(new FlyerBlockImage() { Width = img.Width, Height = img.Height, Resolution = item.Metadata["resolution"].AsInt32, Image = item.Filename });
    }

    b.Images = flyerBlockImages
                    .OrderBy(img => img.Resolution)
                    .ToList();

    // ProcessProductsForBlock(b);

    // setting all col and row span to 1 x 1 for other pubs blocks
    if (!flyer.IsBlockedFlyer)
    {
        b.ColSpan = 1;
        b.RowSpan = 1;
    }
}
```

I believe my main slowdown occurs at this point:

```
foreach (var item in imagesForBlock)
{
    imgStream = await _blockRepo.OpenDataAsync(item.Id);
    img = Image.FromStream(imgStream);
    flyerBlockImages.Add(new FlyerBlockImage() { Width = img.Width, Height = img.Height, Resolution = item.Metadata["resolution"].AsInt32, Image = item.Filename });
}
```

As I am going through each item then doing a pull from my repository. Is there a quicker way to do this? I can only think of a foreach loop. I am targeting .Net5 so I believe I can't use ForeachAsync.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you need all images in memory, then all you can do maybe is [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop). Second thing that you can try is (if you know format of all pictures) to read only header of picture in loop (because you don't need all data in this example).

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET 5 is end-of-life and no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information.